# How to convert Scala Document to JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, akka, mongo-scala-driver

I want to convert variable `message` which is of type `scala.Seq[Scala.Document]` to JSON format in following code:

> ```
> path("getMessages"){
>           get {
>             parameters('roomname.as[String]) {
>               (roomname) =>
>                 try {
>                   val messagesByGroupName = MongoDatabase.collectionForChat.find(equal("groupChatName",roomname)).toFuture()
>                   val messages = Await.result(messagesByGroupName,60.seconds)
>                   println("Messages:"+messages)
>                   complete(messages)
>                 }
>                 catch {
>                   case e:TimeoutException =>
>                     complete("Reading file timeout.")
>             }
>           }
>         }
> ```

But it is giving me error on ***complete(messages)*** line. It is not accepting message of that type.

I tried to convert it into JSON by using following :

> ```
> import play.api.libs.json._
>
> object MyJsonProtocol{
>   implicit object ChatFormat extends Format[Chat] {
>     def writes(c: Chat) : JsValue = {
>       val chatSeq = Seq (
>         "sender" -> JsString(c.sender),
>         "receiver" -> JsString(c.receiver),
>         "message" -> JsString(c.message),
>         "groupChatName" -> JsString(c.groupChatName),
>       )
>       JsObject(chatSeq)
>     }
>
>
>     def reads(value: JsValue) = {
>       JsSuccess(Chat("","","",""))
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

But it is not working.

My **Chat.scala** class is as follows:

> ```
> import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Reads, Writes}
>
> class Chat(var sender:String,var receiver:String,var message:String, var groupChatName:String){
>   def setSenderName(senderName:String) = {
>     sender = senderName
>   }
>   def setReceiverName(receiverName:String) = {
>     receiver = receiverName
>   }
>   def setMessage(getMessage:String) = {
>     message = getMessage
>   }
>   def setGroupChatName(chatName:String) = {
>     groupChatName = chatName
>   }
> }
>
> object Chat {
>   def apply(sender: String, receiver: String, message: String, groupname: String): Chat
>   = new Chat(sender, receiver, message,groupname)
>
>   def unapply(arg: Chat): Option[(String, String, String,String)] = ???
>   implicit val requestReads: Reads[Chat] = Json.reads[Chat]
>   implicit val requestWrites: Writes[Chat] = Json.writes[Chat]
> }
> ```

I am also not able to figure out what to write in *unapply* method.
I am new to scala and akka.

*EDIT:*
My **MongoDatabase.scala** which has collection is as follows:

> ```
> object MongoDatabase {
>   val chatCodecProvider = Macros.createCodecProvider[Chat]()
>
>   val codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
>     CodecRegistries.fromProviders(chatCodecProvider),
>     DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
>   )
>   implicit val system = ActorSystem("Scala_jwt-App")
>   implicit val executor: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher
>   val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
>   val databaseName = sys.env("database_name")
>   // Getting mongodb database
>   val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName).withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
>   val registrationCollection = sys.env("register_collection_name")
>   val chatCollection = sys.env("chat_collection")
>   // Getting mongodb collection
>   val collectionForUserRegistration: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection(registrationCollection)
>   collectionForUserRegistration.drop()
>   val collectionForChat: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection(chatCollection)
>   collectionForChat.drop()
> }
> ```

And if try to change   `val collectionForChat: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection(chatCollection)`

to

`val collectionForChat: MongoCollection[Chat] = database.getCollection[Chat](chatCollection)`

then I get error on in *saveChatMessage()* method below:

> ```
> def saveChatMessage(sendMessageRequest: Chat) : String = {
>     val senderToReceiverMessage : Document = Document(
>       "sender" -> sendMessageRequest.sender,
>       "receiver" -> sendMessageRequest.receiver,
>       "message" -> sendMessageRequest.message,
>       "groupChatName" -> sendMessageRequest.groupChatName)
>     val chatAddedFuture = MongoDatabase.collectionForChat.insertOne(senderToReceiverMessage).toFuture()
>     Await.result(chatAddedFuture,60.seconds)
>     "Message sent"
>   }
> ```

on `val chatAddedFuture = MongoDatabase.collectionForChat.insertOne(senderToReceiverMessage).toFuture()` this line since it accepts data of type **Seq[Document]** and I am trying to add data of type **Seq[Chat]**

Comment: Check the following link: https://lansalo.com/2018/05/07/custom-json-serializer/

Comment: messageByGroupName is of type Future [ scala.Seq [ scala.Document ] ]

Comment: When you say "But it is not working", how is it not working?

Comment: Please check the edited section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that `MongoDatabase.collectionForChat.find(equal("groupChatName",roomname))` returns either `Seq[Chat]`, or `Chat`. Both of them are the same for play.

You have 2 options:

1. Adding the default format on the companion object:

   ```
   object Chat {
       implicit val format: Format[Chat] = Json.format[Chat]
   }
   ```

   In this case you can delete the object `MyJsonProtocol` which is not used.
2. In case you want to keep your own serializers(i.e. `MyJsonProtocol`), you need to rename `MyJsonProtocol` into `Chat`. This way the `complete` route will be able to find the implicit Format.

Comment: My **MongoDatabase.collectionForChat.find(equal("groupChatName",roomname))** line is actually return **Seq[Document]**

Comment: @RuchirDixit, so does my answer help you?

Comment: No. Because it would work perfectly if my code would have retuned Seq[Chat] or Chat but it ain't.

Comment: @RuchirDixit, Are you sure? Did you try to rename `MyJsonProtocol` into `Chat`? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: yes I tried that but it is not able to get access to Chat class.

Answer (score 0):

1. create case class for the message object you want to send
   for example:

```
case class MyMessage(sender: String, receiver: String, message: String, groupChatName: String)
```

2. You should create Format for the type of case class

```
implicit val MessageTypeFormat = Json.format[MyMessage]
```

3. if complete should get JSON type - then call complete `myMessage` when `myMessage` is an instance of MyMessage.

```
complete(Json.toJson(myMessage))
```

Comment: I don't think this will help the PO, since he deliberately implemented a class where the fields are mutables. Therefore I think that defining a case class is not what he meant.

Comment: Yes exactly. Here I need to use setter methods so I cant use case class.

Comment: You can make it with class also, or define some `var` variables

Comment: Which is anyway a bad practice